# How pages render in a home page with PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, codeigniter

In ASP.NET MVC applications can use dynamic pages as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with RenderBody () method that renders the content of a page in another.

**How I can render the content pages on a main (index.php) page PHP Case 1, with the Codeigniter Framework and Case 2, normally without the framework?**

Excuse my English, as it is not my native language!!

Regards,
Mauriciohz

Comment: You want to embed the php page on asp.net mvc page?

Answer (score 1):

In Normal PHP,
You can use any of `include, require , include_once or require_once`.

In **Codeigniter**,

You can load content part alone with use of below code:

```
$this->load->view("view_file_name");
```

here `view_file_name` is your view file which exist inside the `applications/view` folder. 
You have to give `without extension`.

**For ex:**

your content file name is "content.php". `applications/view/content.php`

You can load as:

```
$this->load->view("content");// without ".php" extension.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [include](http://php.net/include) or [require](http://php.net/require) function in php.
Example

```
include('path');
require('path');
include_once('path');
require_once('path');
```

The `_once` would make sure that the file is never included multiple times throughout the script.